# jquery mobile ajax submit from dialog form

Tags: ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I have ajax form that is working on normal jquery mobile page but when I transfer it on dialog it doesn't work. My script doesn't read the click event w/c is set, and by default it sends all the values on same page which is wrong. Did I missed out something? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Values are sending to this url which is wrong:

```
http://localhost/MyFolder/views/maintenance/RegionAdd.html?triggerActivity=region&triggerAction=add&regionDesc=test&area=test222
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost/MyFolder/model/maintenance/maintenance_process.php?triggerActivity=region&triggerAction=add&regionDesc=test&area=test222
```

Please see the script below.

JS: (located on RegionAdd.html)

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
    $("#submit-region").click(function(){
        //var regionDesc = $("#regionDesc").val();
        //console.log(regionDesc);
        var formData = $("#ajaxForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "../../model/maintenance_process.php",
             cache: false,
             data: formData,
             success: onSuccess
        });
            //e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

HTML5: (located on RegionAdd.html)

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <form id='ajaxForm'>
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Add Region</h1>
                <button type='submit' data-theme="a" data-icon="check" data-mini="true" id="submit-region">Save</button>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="content-primary">
                    <input type="hidden" name="triggerActivity" id="triggerActivity" value="region"  />
                    <input type="hidden" name="triggerAction" id="triggerAction" value="add"  />
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="regionDesc">Region</label>
                            <input type="text" name="regionDesc" id="regionDesc" value=""  />
                        </li>
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="area">Area</label>
                            <input type="text" name="area" id="area" value=""  />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <h4 id="message"></h4>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /content -->
        </form>
    </div><!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the form is being submitted on the default way, despite your binding.

You can try something like that:

```
$("form.ajaxForm").live("submit", handleForm);
```

and on handleForm function implement your ajax call.